# Python Regex Find match group of range of non digits after hyphen and if range is not present ignore rest of pattern

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm newer to more advanced regex concepts and am starting to look into look behinds and lookaheads but I'm getting confused and need some guidance. I have a scenario in which I may have several different kind of release zips named something like:

```
v1.1.2-beta.2.zip
v1.1.2.zip
```

I want to write a one line regex that can find match groups in both types. For example if file type is the first zip, I would want three  match groups that look like:

```
v1.1.2-beta.2.zip
Group 1: v1.1.2
Group 2: beta
Group 3. 2
```

or if the second zip one match group:

```
v1.1.2.zip
Group 1: v1.1.2
```

This is where things start getting confusing to me as I would assume that the regex would need to assert if the hyphen exists and if does not, only look for the one match group, if not find the other 3.

```
(v[0-9.]{0,}).([A-Za-z]{0,}).([0-9]).zip
```

This was the initial regex I wrote witch successfully matches the first type but does not have the conditional. I was thinking about doing something like match group range of non digits after hyphen but can't quite get it to work and don't not know to make it ignore the rest of the pattern and accept just the first group if it doesn't find the hyphen

```
([\D]{0,}(?=[-]) # Does not work
```

Can someone point me in the right right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following regex:

```
(v\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(?:[-]([A-Za-z]+))?((?:\.\d+)*)\.zip
```

This thus produces three groups: the first one the version, the second is optional: a dash `-` followed by alphabetical characters, and then an optional sequence of dots followed by numbers, and finally `.zip`.

If we ignore the `\.zip` suffix (well I assume this is rather trivial), then there are still three groups:

**`(v\d+(?:\.\d+)*)`**: a regex group that starts with a `v` followed by `\d+` (one or more digits). Then we have a *non-capture* group (a group starting with `(?:..)` that captures `\.\d+` a dot followed by a sequence of one or more digits. We repeat such subgroup zero or more times.

**`(?:[-]([A-Za-z]+))?`**: a capture group that starts with a hyphen `[-]` and then one or more `[A-Za-z]` characters. The capture group is however optional (the `?` at the end).

**`((?:\.\d+)*)`**: a group that again has such `\.\d+` non-capture subgroup, so we capture a dot followed by a sequence of digits, and this pattern is repeated zero or more times.

For example:

```
rgx = re.compile(r'(v\d+(?:\.\d+)*)([-][A-Za-z]+)?((?:\.\d+)*)\.zip')
```

We then obtain:

```
>>> rgx.findall('v1.1.2-beta.2.zip')
[('v1.1.2', '-beta', '.2')]
>>> rgx.findall('v1.1.2.zip')
[('v1.1.2', '', '')]
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining this regex in a little more detail for me? I just want to understand properly

Comment: @ReaganKirby: yes, one minute.

Comment: The only issue here is we want to exclude the hyphen from the match on the first group

Comment: @ReaganKirby: well no hyphen is part of the first pattern, updated.

Comment: What I mean is if the hyphen exists I would want to match beta instead of -beta. Other than that this is perfect and makes sense

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and clear explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = ['v1.1.2-beta.2.zip', 'v1.1.2.zip']
final_results = [re.findall('[a-zA-Z]{1}[\d\.]+|(?<=\-)[a-zA-Z]+|\d+(?=\.zip)', i) for i in s]
groupings = ["{}\n{}".format(a, '\n'.join(f'Group {i}: {c}' for i, c in enumerate(b, 1))) for a, b in zip(s, final_results)]
for i in groupings:
  print(i)
  print('-'*10)
```

Output:

```
v1.1.2-beta.2.zip
Group 1: v1.1.2
Group 2: beta
Group 3: 2
----------
v1.1.2.zip
Group 1: v1.1.2.
----------
```

Note that the result garnered from `re.findall` is:

```
[['v1.1.2', 'beta', '2'], ['v1.1.2.']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would approach this using `re.search`.  Note that we don't need lookarounds here; just a fairly complex pattern will do the job.

```
import re

regex = r"(v\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(?:-(\w+)\.(\d+))?\.zip"

str1 = "v1.1.2-beta.2.zip"
str2 = "v1.1.2.zip"
match = re.search(regex, str1)

print(match.group(1))
print(match.group(2))
print(match.group(3))

print("\n")
match = re.search(regex, str2)

print(match.group(1))

v1.1.2
beta
2

v1.1.2
```

### Demo

If you don't have a ton of experience with regex, providing an explanation of each step probably isn't going to bring you up to speed.  I will comment, though, on the use of `?:` which appears in some of the parentheses.  In that context, `?:` tells the regex engine *not* to capture what is inside.  We do this because you only want to capture (up to) three specific things.